# Only one level of a four-level factor is showing in ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, factors, levels

I am using the following code to produce a boxplot with a density plot:

```
ggplot(data_alk_pan, aes(x = PAN, y = MEAS_RESULT, fill = PAN)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(levels(data_alk_pan$PAN), "\n(N=",table(data_alk_pan$PAN),")", sep="")) +
  labs(y = "Concentration (mg/l)", x = "Pan") +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    aes(thickness = stat(pdf*n)),
    adjust = 0.5,
    justification = -.5,
    .width = 0,
    point_colour = NA
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, varwidth = TRUE)
```

It works perfectly for every other factor I have in my data (i.e. if I point to a different column in my dataframe other than PAN) but for some reason it will only show the first level of the factor PAN.

I have checked that R recognises all of the levels in the factor by running the following:

```
levels(data_alk_pan$PAN)
```

which returns

```
[1] "Pan_01"  "Pan_02"  "Pan_03"  "Pan_all"
```

which is what I would expect.  However, only the first level (Pan_01) is showing in the plot.  All of the levels have data (i.e. n>0 for all levels).

Any thoughts on what I am missing or what I can do to get all four levels to show in the plot?

Updated query to include some of the data:

```
> dput(data_alk_pan[1:200, c(8,13)])
structure(list(MEAS_RESULT = c(170, 180, 150, 140, 160, 140, 
330, 130, 130, 210, 130, 130, 310, 400, 200, 160, 160, 160, 170, 
170, 220, 170, 200, 240, 200, 190, 200, 180, 190, 240, 250, 260, 
280, 270, 250, 290, 260, 260, 250, 230, 270, 260, 220, 260, 250, 
310, 270, 86, 270, 150, 290, 290, 300, 290, 270, 210, 280, 300, 
390, 270, 190, 240, 240, 260, 210, 250, 210, 220, 190, 260, 210, 
190, 240, 280, 240, 210, 220, 220, 200, 250, 310, 260, 290, 280, 
180, 280, 310, 310, 300, 300, 280, 190, 180, 180, 200, 210, 180, 
280, 390, 290, 320, 310, 320, 260, 330, 330, 390, 300, 350, 270, 
190, 180, 310, 270, 300, 270, 330, 310, 320, 310, 340, 330, 340, 
270, 340, 57, 360, 28, 320, 170, 21, 370, 320, 330, 430, 340, 
300, 350, 300, 300, 340, 260, 270, 230, 180, 210, 210, 240, 230, 
260, 250, 230, 250, 270, 280, 170, 190, 190, 190, 180, 190, 250, 
250, 260, 270, 180, 260, 260, 260, 260, 250, 260, 280, 290, 130, 
150, 190, 180, 190, 240, 270, 260, 230, 220, 170, 190, 270, 270, 
260, 280, 260, 260, 270, 280, 290, 270, 190, 230, 240, 170), 
    PAN = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Pan_01", 
    "Pan_02", "Pan_03", "Pan_all"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide (dummy) data that would show this problem with the code? I think 2-3 rows per factor level should do it.

Comment: I have just generated some dummy data using `data_alk_pan <- data.frame(PAN = factor(sample(
  c("Pan_01", "Pan_02", "Pan_03", "Pan_all"), 40, TRUE)),
  MEAS_RESULT = rnorm(40))` and your code generates the expected plot. This means that the problem lies somewhere in your data, which you haven't included in the question. Can you please edit the question to include the output of `dput(data_alk_pan)`. Otherwise, we can only guess at what's wrong here.

Comment: What does `table(data_alk_pan$PAN)` return? I suspect some levels might be empty.

Comment: I have updated my question to include an extract of the data (apologies).  `table(data_alk_pan$PAN` returns `Pan_01  Pan_02  Pan_03 Pan_all 
      998       953      2006      1049 ` so I don't see any empty levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code there seems no problem. Try to update your packages and run them in a clean environment. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdist)
ggplot(data_alk_pan, aes(x = PAN, y = MEAS_RESULT, fill = PAN)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste(levels(data_alk_pan$PAN), "\n(N=",table(data_alk_pan$PAN),")", sep="")) +
  labs(y = "Concentration (mg/l)", x = "Pan") +
  ggdist::stat_halfeye(
    aes(thickness = stat(pdf*n)),
    adjust = 0.5,
    justification = -.5,
    .width = 0,
    point_colour = NA
  ) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, varwidth = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  I will make sure everything is updated and give it another go.  Very odd indeed that it worked for some of my data but not for this factor.  Thanks again for your time :-)